# Red Black Tree Program crashes

Tags: c, tree, crash

I'm trying to write an implementation for a Red Black Tree algorithm in C but after executing function insert() I get a crash and program stops working. This function firstly find a place in which new value should be added and then it execute another function called Correct_Tree which is responsible for correcting nodes with right order and colors.

There are few warnings I get but don't know how too fix them, other functions built in same way work fine.

```
|69|warning: conflicting types for 'correct_tree' [enabled by default]|

|40|note: previous implicit declaration of 'correct_tree' was here|
```

Same warnings point to function `Rot_L`, I don't know if this warnings cause my crashes. I will be thankful for every answer, if you need more information, let me know. Sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker.

Here are these functions: http://ideone.com/hsYyES
and structure looks like this:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    int key_amounts;
    char color;
    struct node *parent;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} *root;

int insert(int n, struct node *start) {
    //if node doesnt exist then add it to the tree otherwise increase amount of    keys

    //if tree is empty add root
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof *root);
        root->value = n;
        root->keys_amount = 0;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        root->up = NULL;
    } else
    if (search(root, n) != NULL) {
        struct node *tmp = search(root, n);
        tmp->keys_amount += 1;
        return 0;
    } else
    //if value is lower than root val then go to left son
    if (n < start->value) {
        //if left son exist then apply function insert for it
        if (start->left != NULL) {
            insert(n, start->left);
        } else {
            //if it doesnt exist then create 
            struct node *new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof *root);
            new->value = n;
            new->keys_amount = 0;
            new->left = NULL;
            new->right = NULL;
            new->up = start;
            start->left = new;
            correct_tree(new);
        }
    } else {
        //if new value is higher than root
        //if right son exist then apply function for it
        if (start->right != NULL) {
            insert(n, start->right);
        } else {
            //if it doesnt exist create new one
            struct node *new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof *root);
            new->value = n;
            new->keys_amount = 0;
            new->left = NULL;
            new->right = NULL;
            new->up = start;
            start->right = new;
            correct_tree(new);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void correct_tree(struct node *start) {
    struct node *tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof *root);
    start->color = 'R';
    while ((start != root) && (start->up->color == 'R')) {
        if (start->up == start->up->up->left) {
            tmp = start->up->up->right; //uncle of start for tmp
            if (tmp->color == 'R') { //case 1
                start->up->color = 'B';
                tmp->color = 'B';
                start->up->up->color='R';
                start = start->up->up;
                continue;
            }
            if (start == start->up->right) { //case 2
                start = start->up;
                rot_L(start);
            }
            start->up->color = 'B'; //case3
            start->up->up->color = 'R';
            rot_R(start->up->up);
            break;
        } else { //mirror cases
            tmp = start->up->up->left;
            if (tmp->color == 'R') { //case 1
                start->up->color = 'B';
                tmp->color = 'B';
                start->up->up->color = 'R';
                start = start->up->up;
                continue;
            }
            if (start == start->up->left) { //case 2
                start = start->up;
                rot_R(start);
            }
            start->up->color = 'B'; //case3
            start->up->up->color = 'R';
            rot_L(start->up->up);
            break;
        }
    }
    root->color = 'B';
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void rot_L(struct node *start) {
    struct node *tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof *root);
    struct node *tmp2 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof *root);
    tmp = start->right;
    if (tmp != NULL) {
        tmp2 = start->up;
        start->right = tmp->left;
        if (start->right != NULL)
            start->right->up = start;
        tmp->left = start;
        tmp->up = tmp2;
        start->up = tmp;
        if (tmp2 != NULL) {
            if (tmp2->left == start)
                tmp2->left = tmp;
            else
                tmp2->right = tmp;
        } else
            root = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `correct_tree` - you've only got `struct node` in your question? Either way, you need to make sure you define your datatypes before you use them - that's what the warnings mean.

Comment: I added ideone link in post

Comment: it's best to paste your code into your question as where ever you've linked to might not exist in the future and then your question is missing the crucial information to make it understandable.

Comment: you don't have to paste all the code, just enough to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Apart from MCVE: Where *exactly* does it crash? On which input? Have you used a *debugger*?

Comment: when it tries to execute correct_tree(), after I commented lines 40 and 61 it works fine, every input I made (like 10,15,20), I didn't use debugger, I'll edit my post in a minute

Comment: I would recommend you to learn using a debugger - it is a friend, allowing you to execute your program step by step monitoring values and giving you an image of what is happenning. And, btw, if it crashes, it should show you *where* (e.g. at which line) it crashes, the error occured, values of variables, callstack, ... so that you would be able to understand *why* it has crashed.

Comment: If commenting out lines that generate warnings makes your code "work" it's a good sign that you should fix those warnings.

Comment: I get rid of warnings by defining functions earlier like you said, I used a debugger and it firstly stopped at this Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                       
0x0000000000400a62 in correct_tree (start=0x6030a0) at main.c:101                                          
101                 if(tmp->color == 'R') //case 1

Comment: I think that my problem is I should add a guard with color because I create a node tmp which equal to start->up->up but if start->up is the root then start->up->up is equal to NULL am I right?

Comment: Treat the warnings you get as errors, fix them. Where is `main` ? Where does it crash ? Is there any input, if yes what input ? Did you run it with a debugger ? Where are your `#include`s ? Did I forget anything?

Comment: I already wrote all answers for this questions.

Comment: You've worked out the problem yourself, but basically, yes you do need to check that any pointers you're accessing aren't `NULL`. When you're debugging it - even after it has crashed - you can print out any variables to see what values they have.

Comment: Is it `key_amounts` or  `key_amount` ? The code you provided in the question does not compile at all, there isn't even a `main` function. And on http://ideone.com/hsYyES there are tons of errors...And please indent your code

Comment: It is because it's not entire code, people here told me to paste only important functions so ofcourse they won't compile... I had to translate names of variations because it's not originally in english that's why there is a mistake, code is not indented because I would have to click 4 times space for every line cuz tab doesn't work in editor...

Comment: @theplayer27 you don't have to put 4 spaces before each line. Just paste the code, then select the code with the mouse and click on the `{}` icon. The more readable your code is, the more people are likely to help you.

Comment: Oh that will help a lot next time, thank you

Comment: @ChrisTurner No it's wrong, it won't try to get the color of tmp if if statement is not correct so I don't know why I get sigsegv there

Comment: I wonder if it's because sometimes tmp points at null because there are like for example only three nodes where A is root and has right = null, left = B, and then we try to add X which is right son of B, then this if statement is correct but A has no right son which I'm trying to set as tmp, so is the code wrong or just input?

Answer (score 0):

The warnings issued by the compiler tell you that you did not declare nor define `correct_node` before calling it. The prototype inferred by the compiler from the call is `int correct_tree(struct node *start);` which is incompatible with the actual definition it encounters later: `void correct_tree(struct node *start)`. Same problem for `rot_L()`. Declare all functions before calling them.

Function `correct_node` is bound to fail because you dereference the `up` links without first checking that they are not `NULL`.  For example the first time you call `correct_node on the`left`or`right`child of the`root` node, you have:

```
start->color = 'R';
while ((start != root) && (start->up->color == 'R')) {
    if (start->up == start->up->up->left) {
```

You do not initialize the `color` of the `root` node allocated by `malloc()`.  There is a small chance that `root->color` may be equal to `'R'`, which will cause `start->up->up->left` to have undefined behavior as `start->up->up` is `NULL`.

Another issue is this:

```
struct node *tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof *root);
```

The object allocated for `tmp` is never used, never freed and `tmp` is overwritten in the loop.  This is a blatant case of memory leak.

The same issue is present twice in `rot_L`, for `tmp` and `tmp2`.

Comment: I reformated insert function to [this](http://ideone.com/wDeWam) and added a [guard](http://ideone.com/W2Zfpj) and it doesn't crash anymore but now I have problem with in order display which looks like [this](http://ideone.com/CxLEMX), debugger shows sigsegv on in_order_tree_walk(start->left);

Comment: I'm afraid you need to use a debugger for this. It would be simpler and safer for `in_order_tree_walk()` to test for `start == NULL`.  If it still crashes, I suspect you have cycles in your tree and you run into an endless recursion,

Comment: is there a way to fix old code by not reformating insert function like I did?

Comment: I swapped in `in_order_tree_walk()` `NULL` to `&S` and it doesn't crash but it only prints last added value

Comment: @theplayer27: I have no clue what you do in your *reformatted* `insert_function()`. What is `S`?  Similarly, your phrase *I swapped in 'in_order_tree_walk()' 'NULL' to '&S'* does not make sense.  Post the whole code to the paste bin, maybe someone will have the patience to read and comment it.  I have to go right now.